# how to disable Airdrop on Mac Book Pro (Retina)?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, wireless-networking

What is the connection between the Remote Disc (it is in your Finder Window, listed under "Devices") and Airdrop (also in there, listed as "Favorites")?

I tried to use a backup external HD, but these two items became *greyed out*, it looked to me my files were transferred somewhere in the "air".

Additionally, before I performed the backup, I turned off the WiFi, but there was still an *hpsetup* listed under WiFi devices. (not a mistake, not network, "device")

When I stopped the backup, actually unplugged the external HD, and turned WiFi back on, this *hpsetup* disappeared. Why?

Answer (score 1):

This disables AirDrop:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkBrowser DisableAirDrop -bool true
```

You have to log out and back in to apply the changes.

[Remote disc](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5287) shows the contents of optical drives of network Macs where DVD or CD sharing is enabled. The remote disc volume is shown by default on Macs without an optical drive. You can hide it from the sidebar from the preferences, but I don't know how to hide it from /Volumes/ or the computer view.